# MapView zooms in to user location, but when I change views and return to mapview, zoom in doesn't work?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, mkmapview

I've coded my map view with a few annotations on it, and it works great. However, for some reason when I click on my MapView on my device, click away, and go back to the MapView, for some reason it doesn't zoom into the user's location (it just shows the map of the entire world). Does anyone know why? See my code below:

**MapViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController  <MKMapViewDelegate> 

    @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *dispensaries;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData *data;

@end
```

**MapViewController.m**

```
#import "MapViewController.h"
#import "MapViewAnnotation.h"
#import "JSONKit.h"

@implementation MapViewController
@synthesize mapView;
@synthesize dispensaries;
@synthesize data;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    NSLog(@"Getting Device Locations");

    NSString *hostStr = @"http://stylerepublicmagazine.com/dispensaries.php";
    NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:hostStr]];
    NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"server output: %@", serverOutput);
    NSMutableArray *array = [[serverOutput objectFromJSONString] mutableCopy];
    dispensaries = [serverOutput objectFromJSONString];
    NSLog(@"%@", [serverOutput objectFromJSONString]);
    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in array) {
        assert([dictionary respondsToSelector:@selector(objectForKey:)]);

        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {[[dictionary objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue], [[dictionary objectForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue]};

        MapViewAnnotation *ann = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] init];
        ann.title = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Name"];
        ann.subtitle = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Address1"];
        ann.coordinate = coord;
        [mapView addAnnotation:ann];

        [mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
        [mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
        [mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];

        self.mapView.delegate = self;
    }
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 2000, 2000);
    [self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];

    MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    point.coordinate = userLocation.coordinate;
    point.title = @"You Are Here";
    point.subtitle = @"Your current location";

    [self.mapView addAnnotation:point];
}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    for (MapViewAnnotation *annotation in self.mapView.annotations) {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = [annotation coordinate];
        CLLocation *annotationLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:coord.latitude longitude:coord.longitude];
        annotation.distance = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:annotationLocation];
    }
}

// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;

// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

- (void)viewDidUnload
{

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Comment: BTW, you will want to [Avoid Synchronous Networking Calls on the Main Thread](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/CommonPitfalls/CommonPitfalls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH4-SW9). It can be immensely annoying for a user if an app becoming unresponsive as it waits for something from a slow network connection. As you're developing your app, you may want to simulate various network conditions using the "network link conditioner" tool, to make sure the experience is acceptable in less than ideal scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a manifestation of running the app on a simulator (because the user's location doesn't change like it does on device). Have you tried running this on a device? It's likely (unless you have something else going on), that you'll get many `didUpdateUserLocation` hits, and thus you won't have the same user experience issues you have on the simulator.

If that fails, you also could have `viewDidLoad` to set the map's `region`. Perhaps using Core Location's `CLLocationManager`.

I suspect you haven't run this on a device, because as I interpret the `didUpdateUserLocation`, this will add another annotation every time the user's location changes. This is especially problematic on a device, because as the GPS warms up, you end up getting a whole series of location changes as it gets more and more accurate (generally with a decreasing `horizontalAccuracy`.

I assume you really don't want to see a dozen "You Are Here" annotations on your map. You might want to make sure that you remove any prior locations (or just rely upon the `MKMapView` default user annotation you get when you turn on "Shows User Location" in IB or set the `showsUserLocation` property).

Also note, you could set `userTrackingMode` to `MKUserTrackingModeFollow`, and the region will be set for you automatically (assuming (a) the user has given you permission; and (b) the user has sufficient cell/WiFi/GPS signal).